# Next.js is putting CSS @import in the middle of CSS files, how to fix?

Tags: css, next.js

I have a Next.js app, which loads a CSS file from a separate external installed node module, and in that external CSS file it has several `@import` statements, loading both local (to the node module) and remote CSS files.

So in `external-module-1/index.css` we have:

```
// index.css
@import 'base.css';
@import 'light.css';
@import 'theme.css';
@import 'dark.css';
@import 'font.css';

// font.css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Noto+Kufi+Arabic:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Armenian:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Bengali:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Canadian+Aboriginal:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Cuneiform&family=Noto+Sans+Devanagari:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Egyptian+Hieroglyphs&family=Noto+Sans+Ethiopic:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Georgian:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Gujarati:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Gurmukhi:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Hebrew:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+JP:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+KR:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Kannada:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Khmer:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Malayalam:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Mono:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Oriya:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Runic&family=Noto+Sans+SC:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Sinhala:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Syriac&family=Noto+Sans+Tamil:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Telugu:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Sans+Thai:wght@400%3B700&family=Noto+Serif+Tibetan:wght@400%3B700&display=swap');

@font-face {
  font-family: 'IMing';
  ...
}

// base.css
@import 'reset.css';
@import 'react-lite-youtube-embed/dist/LiteYouTubeEmbed.css';
@import '@code-hike/mdx/dist/index.css';
@import url('https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/katex@0.16.0/dist/katex.min.css');

#__next {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
}
```

And inside the Next.js `pages/_app.js` we have:

```
import 'external-module-1/index.css'
```

However, it shows up with seemingly a concatenated CSS file in production which google doesn't like:

[image]

Notice how the `@import` is in the middle of the file, if you scroll all the way to the right you will see a warning:

> Define @import rules at the top of the stylesheet

How do I fix this? I'm not sure if this is causing an error, but my styles are working fine locally in development, but not working in production, so not sure if this is the culprit. In my case, it appears the fonts aren't loading, maybe because of that `@import` problem.